# Is key stored in HashMap actaully points to the value in HashMap

Tags: java, collections

In a HashMap we know when we store the key and value , actually a Map.entry object is populated where Map.entry.key is mapped to key inserted in hashMap and Map.entry.value is mapped to value inserted in hashmap . Now my question is how is the supplied key is related to supplied value in a hashmap .

I mean if my understanding is correct key is not referencing directly to the value of hashMap and hence even if this reference is made to null , it should not impact the value in hashmap getting garbage collected.

Comment: You can find source code on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is not correct. A key-value pair is stored as an object of a class called `Map.Entry`. A `null` key is also valid key in a `HashMap`, and its Hashvalue equals `0`. If you specify a key as `null` it will store as a unique key-value pair and any more entries with `null` key will override the previous entry. The object inside `Map.Entry.key` maybe `null` , but it itself is being stored in an LinkedList(Bucket of Entries) of hashMap and hence will not be `Garbage Collected`. To remove a Object from HashMap call the `.remove(key)` method instead of nullifying keys and depending on `GC`

Answer (score 0):

You understanding may be right. I suggest you to read the source code from JDK.

Actually, `Hashmap` or other hash collections often use a array . In java

```
Entry<K,V>[] table
```

the keys `hashcode() % tableSize` (just for understanding) determine which index the key stores in the table array.